# Meteor childtemplate rendered event not call firsttime within an each loop

Tags: meteor

I have 3 items. When i try to render all these items. The event rendered only gets called on the last the. The first time the event does not get triggered. Can someone maybe help me? The problem is on line 5, that is only executed 2 times instead of 3 times. I am using version 0.8.1 of meteor.

```
var tryCount = 0;

Template.singleaction.rendered = function(){
    var originalContext = this;
    console.log("Rendered event fired");
    var ensureExecution = function(){
        if (originalContext.$('.formtemplate-' + originalContext.data.action).length < 1 && tryCount < 10){
            setTimeout(ensureExecution, 200);
            tryCount++;
        }
        else{
            if (originalContext.data){
                var formtemplate = FollowupImplementationController.getActionTemplate(originalContext.data);
                if (formtemplate){
                    var entity = FollowupImplementationController.getCurrentEntity();
                    var toInject = UI.renderWithData(Template[formtemplate], entity);
                    UI.insert(toInject, originalContext.$('.formtemplate-' + originalContext.data.action)[0]);
                }
            }
            tryCount = 0;
        }
    }
    ensureExecution();
}
```

Below the code of the parent template

```
<template name="followupimpactions">
    <legend>Acties:</legend>
    <ol id="actions">
        {{#each actions}}
        {{>singleaction}}
        {{/each}}
    </ol>
</template>
```

Below the code of the child template.

```
<template name="singleaction">
    <li>
        {{displaytext}}
        <div class="formtemplate-{{action}}">

        </div>
    </li>
</template>
```

UPDATE!!!
I found out that this only happens when i switch the items. I have isolated the problem. The full code can be seen on http://pastebin.com/Jsw4AzFN and the example can be visited on http://isolation.meteor.com/ .

The behavior can be reproduces by going to the console and call SwitchItems(), there you will see that for item4, 5, 6 the rendered callback is not fired anymore but for item 7 it is.

Can someone tell me how can i make sure that all items are rendered, because it are different items.

Comment: I'm having the same problem here. I have to wrap child events, even rendered on Meteor.setTimeout with some timer. That's ugly. If I find something better I'll let you know.

Comment: I have found the other ugly but maybe nicer solution. I found out that in blaze the each is looking for a _id to discriminate. If there is no _id provided. Then it will look for the array index. So if you replace the array with another array. The indexes that already existed don't change so the rendered event is not fired. I hope im explaining this the right way. See this link for more information https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/meteor-talk/6PFMDOWWP1o/baAgaXQSbH4J

Comment: In fact that makes more sense. Pass a cursor instead of an array. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor just updates the first 3 templates, so rendered is not called for those.

Blaze rendered is only called for templates that get rendered for the first time.

Blaze Each uses the array index for the each if no _id is supplied
[Blaze notes #each](http://meteorpedia.com/read/Blaze_Notes#%7B%7B#each%7D%7D)
So adding a _id property with unique ids for the objects would force blaze to remove the existing items and add new ones. Thus solving your problem